# Extracting embedded documents from all word documents in a folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to vba and I have a question. I have written a macro in word to open and save embedded documents in the active document. The code I wrote is below:

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim num As Integer
    Dim AD As Document
    Set AD = ActiveDocument

    Dim numObjects As Integer
    numObjects = AD.InlineShapes.Count

    'MsgBox numObjects  ' prints "11"

    For num = 1 To numObjects
        If AD.InlineShapes(num).Type = 1 Then
            'it's an embedded OLE type so open it.
            AD.InlineShapes(num).OLEFormat.Open
            AD.InlineShapes(num).OLEFormat.Object.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Ankita\Desktop\New folder\x.xlsx", FileFormat:=51


        End If
    Next num

End Sub
```

What I would like to do is extract all embedded documents in all the word documents present in a source folder and save all of them in a destination folder.

I understand that I would have to access the word docs and loop through them and have the same code snippet as above, but how exactly do I write it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The First step would be to Get a list of all the files in the source folder that you are looking to extract from.

```
Sub GetAllFiles(Folder As String, StrArray() As String)
    'Stores all file names from a folder into a string array.
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Folder)
    i = 1
    'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ReDim Preserve StrArray(i)
        StrArray(i) = objFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next objFile

    If i = 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve StrArray(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

The next step is to filter out all but the Word Document Files.

```
Dim FileSpec(1) As String
FileSpec(0) = Source & "\*.doc"
FileSpec(1) = Source & "\*.docx"

Sub GetFileList(ByRef FileSpec() As String, objDict As Object)
    Dim FileName As String
    objDict.RemoveAll
    On Error GoTo NoFilesFound
    For i = LBound(FileSpec) + 1 To UBound(FileSpec)
        FileName = Dir(FileSpec(i))
'       Loop until no more matching files are found
        Do While FileName <> ""
            If Not objDict.Exists(FileName) Then objDict.Add FileName, 0
            FileName = Dir()
        Loop
    Next i
    If objDict.count = 0 Then GoTo NoFilesFound
Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NoFilesFound:
'ERROR HANDLING
End Sub
```

This Adds all the files with .doc or .docx extensions to a Dictionary as keys and a value of 0. You could change this around to be a key of whatever number with the data as the filename, but that is your choice.

From here, you need to Open and call your Sub for each item in the dictionary.

```
Sub OpenAndExtract()
Dim AD As Document
    Documents(ActiveDocument.FullName).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    For each Key in objDict
        Set Ad = Documents.Open(Source & "\" & Key).Activate
        Call Extract
    Next
End Sub
```

And that is it roughly. Please note that you will probably have to change up the way that you chose your destination folder (by taking a parameter or setting up a global variable, etc). I don't know the organization of the project you are working on so you are likely going to have to go about this piecewise, getting one part to work slowly. Also, I wrote this almost all this by hand in the editor here, so it is entirely possible I have some syntax wrong somewhere. Don't take it as the word of god, but it should get you well on your way to your goal.